# Bigquery API: Running query with destinationTable does not save results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to automate a daily aggregation process. The idea is to run on a few tables from one dataset, and save their results to a table on a second dataset. My user has permissions on both relevant datasets.

My request looks as follows

```
        var request = {
        "maxResults": 10000,
        "useQueryCache": false,
        "destinationTable": {
              "projectId": "project_name_obfuscated",
              "datasetId": "project_114151_shared",
              "tableId": "test123"
            },
        "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        "allowLargeResults": true,
        "query": "query syntax here"
      };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, "project_name_obfuscated");
```

(I've obfuscated the name of the projects and the query itself for confidentiality reasons).

The query actually runs fine, however, it's not being saved into the designated project/dataset/table which I've defined.

In the BQ UI I'm seeing something like:

```
Job ID: project_name_obfuscated:job_NhkQpi110p3i5yoOO7nzXp3tTKY
Start Time: 5:47pm, 20 Oct 2014
End Time: 5:47pm, 20 Oct 2014
Bytes Processed: 0 B
Destination Table: project_name_obfuscated:_138c3340e691065e8db0b55781b5a41c6b4bcd49.anonev_SOiiRC10lfetj000kcj4rmXNc5E
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using arguments which are only available via the Jobs.insert in the Jobs.query method. Jobs.query is intended for quick, synchronous queries, and doesn't support the full range of options available in Jobs.insert, which is the asynchronous version.

Try something like:

```
var configuration = {
  "query": {
    "useQueryCache": false,
    "destinationTable": {
          "projectId": "project_name_obfuscated",
          "datasetId": "project_114151_shared",
          "tableId": "test123"
        },
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    "allowLargeResults": true,
    "query": "query syntax here"
  }
};
var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
};

var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "project_name_obfuscated");

var jobId = jobResult.jobReference.jobId;

// The job might not actually be done; wait until it is marked
// complete.
var sleepTimeMs = 500;
while (true) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      "maxResults": 10000);
    if (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Needs a small correction in order to mark as solved - the entire content of the configuration needs to be behind another "query" parameter (e.g. configuration->query-><options>). Otherwise, you get errors from the API.
   var configuration = {
    "query": {
        "useQueryCache": false,

Comment: Thanks. Fixed (looks like your proposed updates were rejected by SO moderators for some reason, but I've applied then anyway).

Comment: I got the following error with the code you wrote:GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Encountered " <ID> ").* "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]