# how to save 2 tables in google big query using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have to make 2 tables where the second table created uses the first table. It looks like this:

```
function saveQueryToTable() {

     var projectId = 'your project';
      var datasetId = 'your dataset';
       var tableId = 'Table 1';
         var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
       query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count' +
           'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare' +
           'WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
         destinationTable: {
        projectId: projectId,
        datasetId: datasetId,
         tableId: tableId
        }
       }
     }
    };

       var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
          Logger.log(queryResults.status);
                    }
           {var projectId = 'your project';
             var datasetId = 'your dataset';
              var tableId = 'Table 2';
                     var job = {
                configuration: {
                        query: {
                query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS                          word_count' +
                             'FROM Table1' +
                            'WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
                 destinationTable: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    }
  }
                     }
           };

           var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
                 Logger.log(queryResults.status);
                  }

                      }
```

How can I use the sleep utilities after the first table creation so that there is enough time for the table to be created and then the second query can access the Table 1?

Comment: This would be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468803/bigquery-api-running-query-with-destinationtable-does-not-save-results

Comment: Whsts wrong eith using utilites.sleep?

Comment: how do I get when the table is created and I can stop the sleep utilities?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the BigQuery.Jobs.insert call should be a QueryResults object that is described in the Response section in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults).

Checking the "jobComplete" property should let you know if you have to keep sleeping or proceed with the second job.